# Array index vs. "user documentation" terminology?

Tags: c++, c, documentation

I have an "array" of bytes that is referenced in some high-level client/developer documentation (which does not contain any programming language or environment specific information). In this document, bytes are currently referred to as "byte 3" or "byte 17", etc. The development environment is C/C++ and the bytes are stored in an array in which the starting index is 0 (naturally).

The problem is that developers may (have) interpreted "byte 3" in the document as meaning either myarray[3] or myarray[2].

What kind of terminology do folks use to make the "byte number" vs. "array index" distinction clear, yet keep it readable to both (non-programmer) clients and developers?

Comment: Why exactly would non-programmer clients care or need to know about the meanings of individual bytes? I would expect anyone with a need to consume this sort of information to be familiar with how arrays are indexed in computer programs.

Comment: I believe when saying "Nr. 3" most people see that as being based in 1, and when saying "Idx. 3" most people see that as being based on 0. I find that intuitive.

Comment: The document is reviewed by client representatives from the executive level down to the developer level. Multiple developers are referencing the document. It has to be clear to everyone. As an example, think of a character string, e.g. like a trademark, that has to be in the executable but where a specific byte of that string is called out in the documentation for some reason.

Comment: Sounds like the documentation process is pretty broken if you're being expected to produce documents which are useful to developers but understandable to executives. I'm sure that's not your fault, though.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Draw a map of the array and label the bytes there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to just directly state where you're starting counting. Another possibility is to use things like "first byte", "seventeenth byte", and so on. A third (the one I usually prefer) is to speak in terms of offsets from the base address.

Comment: +1 for offset from base address

Comment: I like this, or at least a variation of it. "First", "second", etc. does seem to be interpreted by most as referring to a sequence starting at "1". I think a combination of terms would work well, something like "the 1st byte of the serial number (serial_num[0]) will be used...".

Comment: +1 for just directly stating it. Sometimes the easiest way to eliminate all possible confusion is just to explicitly state things.

Answer (score 4):

> What kind of terminology do folks use to make the "byte number" vs. "array index" distinction clear, yet keep it readable to both (non-programmer) clients and developers?

Array indices start at 0. (Or, 1. Take a stance and state it in your design document.)

Comment: And if the array index doesn't match the byte number, throw in a nice comment where myarray[] is defined.

Comment: +1 - If you risk multiple interpretations, mitigate the risk by explicitly stating it in the document.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove all reference to the position in the array from your documentation.

Give things a meaningfull name.

Then have constants in your program that map the name to a position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the documentation if exists a "byte 0".